# VB.NET Tool for Image Printing - Quality Ajustments

Tags: vb.net, printing, image

I'm developing a tool for easy picture printing with a canon selpy cp800. The Image is printed with the following methods:

```
Private Sub BtnPrintClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ptnPrint.Click
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        pdPrintImage.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PdPrintImagePrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pdPrintImage.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_dPictures(_sPictures(_iActiveImage)).Picture, e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds)
End Sub
```

_dPictures(_sPictures(_iActiveImage)).Picture --> object of the type image

I didn't do anything with this image. It's only loaded with the Image.FromFile() method.

Within the following image you can see my problem. This is a scan of the image printed with this method (top) and a scan of the same image printed with the windows picture viewer. You see, the first image you see the tonal errors in the background and the shadows.

[image]

Has anyone an idea to fix this?

Comment: looks liek a bit-depth issue.. or dithering..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't a bit-depth issue as Boo mentioned, it might help to set one or both of these

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
```

before doing the .DrawImage.

Answer (score -1):

the best quality I achieved as follows:
1) I put a picture into pdf using components iTextsharp.
2) print the pdf